# Adobe Air + PC or Mobile Debug

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, adobe

Is there a way when debugging using the Adobe Air Debugger to determine if the app is being run on a mobile device via USB or on the PC? I would like to find a more streamlined way of doing it so that I do not need to constantly change my file locations (applicationStorageDirectory, etc).

Thanks.

Comment: quote: "do not need to constantly change my file locations" why would you need to change anything? I've never heard of such a thing unless you purposely created yourself that problem. I've published/debug dozens of apps on Ios/Android without ever having to change any paths or folder anywhere.You must be doing something wrong. Next: the Capability class gives you all the info you need to figure out where your app is running.

Comment: When I am debugging on the PC, i have the user file go to the documentsDirectory and then on Mobile I have it go to applicationStorageDirectory. I have tried to set the PC to the same as Mobile, however it never sees the file as being there. Thus my dilemma.

Comment: On desktop or mobile there's no problem using appStorageDirectory for reading or writing. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: That comment was incredibly unhelpful. Instead of trying to determine more of what I was doing and the issues I saw, you said I was doing something wrong.
In any case, I think my issue has less of accessing the appStorageDirectory in each individual debug session, and more of a persisting between debug sessions. The reason I say this is that I get no error trying to write to the location, however my app does a check to see if a specific file is present (found in appStorageDirectory), and if not then copies to it. This check returns false everytime I debug. Is there a setting for this?

Comment: I can see why you see it that way but maybe you could also agree that if you didn't have to switch folders depending on where you debug, things will be a lot easier for you. If you agree then you can see that I'm trying to help you. If not you can always look into the Capability class as I said in another comment. You can use that to see where you debug. the appStorageDirectory has no restriction so copying there should not fail whether on desktop or mobile. If your copying fails that might be a code problem, let's see it.

Comment: Copying isnt what seems to be failing. It appears that between debug sessions the file I am looking for gets deleted from the applicationStorageDirectory. I dont receieve errors when I copy or write to the new file. I have nothing set up in my code to delete the file upon app exit. If my understanding of the appStorageDirectory is correct, then it gets deleted when the app is uninstalled, is that no similar to debugging, therefore when I end the present debug session it would remove all files in that directory? I  would love to streamline so I dont need to change folders between PC or mobile.

Comment: I use that directory to set my db files and other and those don't get deleted . I always put them in a folder though, could that be the difference? Not sure. I know there's the option to clear data at startup in FB 4.7 but I always have it unchecked. You sure you don't have a code that clear out this folder?

Comment: Thats incredibly wierd. Im not able to check a few other things at the moment. I do have code to delete the db, however it requires a certain keystroke, and when I run with the documentsDirectory (presently for PC debug), it does not delete between, so switching locations would not miraculously trigger. I will check that clear option tonight and see what the status of that is.

Comment: comment out the code that clear out the directory and test that just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my is that the "Clear application data on each launch." was checked, therefore although it was saving in the correct location, every time I had launched the debug, it was clearing the applicationStorageDirectory location. Thank you for your help.